# pushing temp changes to heroku and then removing them (from git)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Sometimes I end up with something I need to debug in my rails app on Heroku. For example, I might output some debug info in a view. Currently, I'll make the changes in my code, commit it to git, then push it up to heroku. Once I'm finished I'll remove the debug code, commit, push to heroku again. The problem is that my git history gets cluttered with this mess. Since my temp code got pushed to heroku I can't change the git history using `rebase`.

Is there a way to do this and clean up my git history?

Please keep in mind my question is really about how to revert the temp changes I made so they do not show up in my git history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to branch off your debug code using `git branch debug` then `git checkout debug`. From there, you can push that to Heroku with the command `git push heroku debug:master`. When it's time to back that out of the codebase, you `git checkout master`, `git push heroku master --force`, to overwrite the debugging code on Heroku, and `git branch -D debug` to remove the debug branch.

Comment: this is awesome, did not realize i could force a push